# Lua compiled scripts on Mac OS X - Intel vs PPC

Tags: macos, lua, cross-compiling, luac

Been using Lua 5.0 in a Mac OS X universal binary app for some years. Lua scripts are compiled using luac and the compiled scripts are bundled with the app. They have worked properly in Tiger and Leopard, Intel or PPC.

To avoid library problems at the time, I simply added the Lua src tree to my Xcode project and compiled as is, with no problems.

It was time to update to a more modern version of Lua so I replaced my source tree with that of 5.1.4. I rebuilt luac using **make macosx** (machine is running Leopard on Intel).

**Uncompiled** scripts work properly in Tiger and Leopard, Intel and PPC, as always.

However, now **compiled** scripts fail to load on PPC machines.

So I rebuilt luac with the 'ansi' flag, and recompiled my scripts. Same error.  Similarly, a build flag of 'generic' produced no joy.

Can anyone please advise on what I can do next?

Comment: More information needed: any error messages upon this failing to load?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lua's compiled scripts are pretty much the raw bytecode dumped out after a short header. The header documents some of the properties of the platform used to compile the bytecode, but the loader only verifies that the current platform has the same properties.

Unfortunately, this creates problems when loading bytecode compiled on another platform, even if compiled by the very same version of Lua. Of course, scripts compiled by different versions of Lua cannot be expected to work, and since the version number of Lua is included in the bytecode header, the attempt to load them is caught by the core.

The simple answer is to just not compile scripts. If Lua compiles the script itself, you only have to worry about possible version mismatches between Lua cores in your various builds of your application, and that isn't hard to deal with.

Actually supporting a full cross compatibility for compiled bytecode is [not easy](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2005-06/msg00048.html). In that email, Mike Pall identified the following issues:

> 1. Endianess: swap on output as needed.
> 2. `sizeof(size_t)`, affects huge string constants: check for overflow    when
>      downgrading.
> 3. `sizeof(int)`, affects`MAXARG_Bx` and `MAXARG_sBx`: check for overflow    when
>      downgrading.
> 4. `typeof(lua_Number)`: easy in C, but only when the host and the    target
>      follow the same FP standard; precision
>      loss when upgrading    (rare case);
>      warn about non-integer numbers when
>      downgrading to    `int32`.

From all the discussions that I've seen about this issue on the mailing list, I see two likely viable approaches, assuming that you are unwilling to consider just shipping the uncompiled Lua scripts.

The first would be to fix the byte order as the compiled scripts are loaded. That turns out to be easier to do than you'd expect, as it can be done by replacing the low-level function that reads the script file without recompiling the core itself. In fact, it can even be done in pure Lua, by supplying your own [chunk reader](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_Reader) function to [lua_load()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_load). This should work as long as the only compatibility issue over your platforms is byte order.

The second is to patch the core itself to use a common representation for compiled scripts on all platforms. This has been described as possible by [Luiz Henrique de Figueiredo](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2005-06/msg00073.html):

> ....
>   I'm convinced that the best route to
>   byte order or cross-compiling is
>   third-party dump/undump pairs. The
>   files ldump.c and lundump.c are
>   completely replaceable; they export a
>   single, well-defined, entry point. The
>   format of precompiled chunks is not
>   sacred at all; you can use any format,
>   as long as ldump.c and lundump.c agree
>   about it. (For instance, Rici Lake is
>   considering writing a text format for
>   precompiled chunks.) 
>   ....

Personally, I'd recommend giving serious consideration to not pre-compiling the scripts and thus avoid the platform portability issues entirely.

**Edit:** I've updated my description of the bytecode header thanks to lhf's comment. I hadn't read this part of the Lua source yet, and I probably should have checked it before being quite so assertive about what information is or is not present in the header.

Here is the fragment from [`lundump.c`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lundump.c.html#luaU_header) that forms a copy of the header matching the running platform for comparison to the bytecode being loaded. It is simply compared with `memcmp()` for an exact match to the header from the file, so any mismatch will cause the stock loader ([`luaU_undump()`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lundump.c.html#luaU_undump)) to reject the file.

```
/*
* make header
*/
void luaU_header (char* h)
{
 int x=1;
 memcpy(h,LUA_SIGNATURE,sizeof(LUA_SIGNATURE)-1);
 h+=sizeof(LUA_SIGNATURE)-1;
 *h++=(char)LUAC_VERSION;
 *h++=(char)LUAC_FORMAT;
 *h++=(char)*(char*)&x;                         /* endianness */
 *h++=(char)sizeof(int);
 *h++=(char)sizeof(size_t);
 *h++=(char)sizeof(Instruction);
 *h++=(char)sizeof(lua_Number);
 *h++=(char)(((lua_Number)0.5)==0);             /* is lua_Number integral? */
}
```

As can be seen, the header is 12 bytes long and contains a signature (4 bytes, "`<esc>Lua`"), version and format codes, a flag byte for endianness, sizes of the types `int`, `size_t`, `Instruction`, and `lua_Number`, and a flag indicating whether `lua_Number` is an integral type.

This allows most platform distinctions to be caught, but doesn't attempt to catch every way in which platforms can differ.

I still stand by the recommendations made above: first, ship compilable sources; or second, customize `ldump.c` and `lundump.c` to store and load a common format, with the additional note that any custom format should redefine the LUAC_FORMAT byte of the header so as to not be confused with the stock bytecode format.

Comment: The bytecode header does contain some info about the platform, such as the size and type of lua_Number and the endianness.

Comment: @lhf, thanks. I've updated my answer to better describe what the header contains.

Comment: Firstly, thanks to everyone who participated in this Question. Big hugs!  I apologize for not responding earlier. 

I've reverted to vers 5 which, for whatever reason, does successfully run compiled scripts across PPC & Intel, for now. 

Longer term, I'm wary of second-guessing future Lua builds with endian issues, so I'll probably ship the uncompiled scripts with my app, and compile them on the host machine as needed. Casual security is an issue though, so I'll have to batch-obfuscate-encrypt the (100s of) scripts and then decrypt them just prior to compilation.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use a patched bytecode loader that supports different endianness.
See [this](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2006-02/msg00507.html).

Answer (score 3):

I would have commented on RBerteig's post, but I apparently don't have enough reputation yet to be able to do so.  In working on bringing LuaRPC up to speed with Lua 5.1.x AND making it work with embedded targets, I've been modifying the ldump.c and lundump.c sources to make them  both a bit more flexible.  The embedded Lua project (eLua) already had some of the patches you can find on the Lua list, but I've added a bit more to make lundump a little more friendly to scripts compiled on different architectures. There's also cross-compilation support provided so that you can build for targets differing from the host system (see luac.c in the same directory as the links below).

If you're interested in checking out the modifications, you can find them in the eLua source repository:
http://svn.berlios.de/wsvn/elua/trunk/src/lua/lundump.c
http://svn.berlios.de/wsvn/elua/trunk/src/lua/lundump.h
http://svn.berlios.de/wsvn/elua/trunk/src/lua/ldump.c

Standard Disclaimer:
I make no claim that the modifications are perfect or work in every situation.  If you use it and find anything broken, I'd be glad to hear about it so that it can be fixed.

Comment: FYI: Our project website can be found here, http://www.eluaproject.net/  and docs that should accompany the 0.6 release (soon, I hope) here: http://elua.berlios.de/beta/ which has notes on using the cross compiler: http://elua.berlios.de/beta/en/using.html#cross

Answer (score 1):

Lua bytecode is not portable. You should ship source scripts with your application.

If download size is a concern, they are generally shorter than the bytecode form.

If intellectual property is a concern, you can use a code obfuscator, and keep in mind that disassembling Lua bytecode is anything but difficult.

If loading time is a concern, you can precompile the sources locally in your installation script.

Answer (score 0):

I conjecture that you compiled the scripts on an Intel box.

Compiled scripts are wildly unportable.  If you really want to precompile scripts, you'll need to include two versions of each compiled script: one for Intel and one for PPC.  Your app will have to interrogate which program it's running on and use the correct compiled script.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I have to provide this as an answer instead even though it's not an appropriate answer to the question asked.  Sorry.

There is an Lua Obfuscator available here:

http://www.capprime.com/CapprimeLuaObfuscator/CapprimeLuaObfuscator.aspx

Full disclosure: I am the author of the obfuscator and I am aware it is not perfect.  Feedback is welcome and encouraged (there is a feedback page available from the above page).